# How do I install the Reddit Unity Lens?

Tags: unity, lenses

So I was looking at Jorge Castro's blog, and I saw that there was a [Reddit](http://reddit.com) [lens for Ubuntu 11.04 Unity](https://launchpad.net/reddit-lens). How do I install it? Is there a PPA?

Comment: I've created a .deb but I didn't get home to test it... I'll make a post on WebUpd8 in a few hours if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download the .deb I've created using Andrew Starr-Bochicchio's packaging from [HERE](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/test/+files/unity-place-reddit_0.1%7Ebzr2-0ubuntu1_all.deb).

Once installed, log out and log back in for Unity Reddit Lens to work.

For more info (like configuring it - you must edit a file for this), see the article on [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/install-unity-reddit-lens-in-ubuntu-deb.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Jorge: I know what you mean but it's not applicable in this case because I've posted a link to the .deb :) I guess I should add that you must log out after installing it, but that's it... Edit: my bad... the link wasn't to the deb though it was supposed to be, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4):

**Ubuntu 11.10 & 12.04**

For Ubuntu 11.10 & 12.04, the Reddit Lens may be installed as follows:

In a terminal, type the following commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa 
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install unity-reddit-lens
```

Then log out and log back in to activate the lens.