# Tracker search for Thunderbird mail?

Tags: thunderbird, tracker

I see a lot of material about it, but mostly very much outdated regarding a Tracker plugin for Thunderbird. There definitely does not seem to be anything official.

What is the best/recommended way, if there is any, to get Tracker to search my Thunderbird mail?

Comment: Could you please clarify as to what you are trying to achieve? Are you looking for something like a Unity lens that keeps a track of all the mails for easy searching? If so, please look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/85367/18887) and let us know :) Thanks :)

Comment: The Tracker I am referring to is http://live.gnome.org/Tracker, so I am speaking in the context of desktop search.

Comment: Did you check out the answer linked in the above comment and see if that is a viable solution?

Comment: Yes, I saw no mention of mail or Thunderbird, and this is not what I am looking for. It has to do with Unity lenses, and I am accessing Tracker through it's own user interface.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Comment: Why? For what reason?

Comment: @mydoghasworms Because it is an old question that hasn't gotten much attention recently. So, if you are no longer searching for an answer or not experiencing this problem anymore the question is obsolete. Has the problem been resolved? (Make sure you include `@Seth` in your reply so I get notified). Thank you.