# Are there any lenses for empathy or pidgin?

Tags: empathy, lenses, pidgin

I see gwibber lenses, is there anything for empathy or pidgin? For search my contacts, open tab chat or others..

Comment: There is a [list of available Ubuntu lenses](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available) on here, but I don't see anything for Pidgin or Empathy. An online search doesn't return any results, either. But if something is eventually found (or made), that list will have to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that not exist, look here: 
[What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)

Obviously these aren't all the lenses available but I don't find anything about pidgin or empathy.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Introducing-Ubuntu-Pidgin-Lens-for-Unity-271043.shtml) is a link to a Softpedia page giving the PPA for a Pidgin Lens. All it does it search for Online Buddies, but I will admit, it's pretty nice.