# Unable to install unity web search lens

Tags: 11.10, unity, lenses

I receive this error:

`unity-place-websearch : Depends: gir1.2-unity-3.0 but it is not installable`

Using 11.10, here's how to replicate:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cscarney/unity-web-place
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-place-websearch
```

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/70060/18612) is the lens you are talking about, correct?

Comment: Yes, the web sources lens.

Answer (score 2):

The Unity Web Search lens is out of date. It requires `gir1.2-unity-3.0` which has been upgraded to `gir1.2-unity-4.0` in 11.10. There isn't much of a way around it except for maybe running 11.04 rather than 11.10, updating the package yourself, or just waiting for someone else to update it.

You *might* be able to change the list of prerequisites for the package to include the newest version of `gir1.2-unity`, but I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: I noticed the dependency was the issue but I doubt it is a dependency in real terms, so I agree, forcing the install should work fine. Also not sure how to force despite dependencies though. I usually just have to force based on architecture :-P