# Installing Lenses and Scopes in Ubuntu 12.04 error

Tags: unity

When I am going  to download a lens or scope in terminal using the codes from  http://www.noobslab.com/2012/01/install-important-lenses-in-ubuntu.html
my computer says could not locate package

I want Contacts Lens
Tomboy Lens 
YouTube Lens
Books Lens
and grooveshark lens

This is what comes in the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-lens-books
```

I have copied the codes in – Harris Rubin yesterday 
and these were the results – Harris Rubin yesterday

```
harris@harris-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RP296UA-ABA:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jsevi83/unity [sudo] password for harris: You are about to add the following PPA to your system: tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted More info: launchpad.net/~jsevi83/+archive/unity Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.4FgF1Cnihn --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//jockey-drivers.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted gpg: "tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted" not a key ID: skipping harris@harris-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RP296UA-ABA:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/lenses – Harris Rubin yesterday 
You are about to add the following PPA to your system: A PPA for new lenses made for atareao-team More info: launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/lenses Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.OiifMH4Lc6 --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//jockey-drivers.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv A3D8A366869FE2DC5FFD79C36A9653F936FD5529 gpg: requesting key 36FD5529 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com gpg: key 36FD5529: public key "Launchpad PPA for atareao" imported – Harris Rubin yesterday 
gpg: Total number processed: 1 gpg: imported: 1 (RSA: 1) harris@harris-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RP296UA-ABA:~$ sudo apt-get update Ign dl.google.com testing InRelease Get:1 dl.google.com testing Release.gpg [189 B] Get:2 dl.google.com testing Release [2,513 B] Ign security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease Ign us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease Ign us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease Get:3 dl.google.com testing/non-free i386 Packages [793 B] Ign download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2 InRelease Get:4 security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B] Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease Ign dl.google.com testing/non-free TranslationIndex Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Get:5 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2 Release.gpg Get:6 security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB] Get:7 ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B] Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Get:5 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B] Hit download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2 Release.gpg Get:6 security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB] Get:7 ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B] Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg Get:8 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B] Hit download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2 Release Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Get:9 ppa.launchpad.net precise Release [11.9 kB] Get:10 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B] Ign dl.google.com testing/non-free Translation-en_US Hit download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2/main i386 Packages Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise Release – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Get:11 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign dl.google.com testing/non-free Translation-en Ign download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2/main TranslationIndex Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise Release Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Get:12 security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [8,976 B] Get:13 ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources [1,524 B] Get:14 ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages [1,089 B] Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages Get:15 security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [14 B] Get:16 security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [4,063 B] Get:17 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB] Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources Get:18 security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [696 B] Get:19 security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [35.0 kB] Get:20 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB] Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Get:21 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB] Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Get:22 security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Get:21 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB] Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources Hit ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex Get:22 security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en Hit security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en Hit security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en Hit security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en Ign download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2/main Translation-en_US Ign download.ebz.epson.net lsb3.2/main Translation-en Get:25 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Get:26 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB] Err ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources 404 Not Found Err ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages 404 Not Found Err ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources 404 Not Found Err ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages 404 Not Found – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US Ign ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Get:27 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources [155 kB] Get:28 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB] Get:29 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B] Get:30 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB] Get:31 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB] Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex Get:32 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [41.7 kB] Get:33 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [1,379 B] Get:34 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [12.3 kB] Get:35 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse S – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Get:36 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [112 kB] Get:37 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [2,439 B] Get:38 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [34.4 kB] Get:39 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1,393 B] Get:40 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [73 B] Get:41 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [71 B] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Get:43 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [73 B] Get:44 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [700 B] Get:45 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [14 B] Get:46 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [2,696 B] Get:47 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [14 B] Get:48 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [559 B] Get:49 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Get:50 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [2,379 B] Get:51 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en Get:52 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [53.7 kB] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en Get:53 us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [21.4 kB] – Harris Rubin yesterday 
Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en Hit us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en Fetched 12.9 MB in 38s (335 kB/s) – Harris Rubin yesterday 
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/… 404 Not Found W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/… 404 Not Found – Harris Rubin yesterday 
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy/ubuntu/dists/… 404 Not Found W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy/ubuntu/dists/… 404 Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Hi give us the way how you have done in your terminal .

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available

Comment: Have you followed the instructions and also put this ([Install Important Lenses in Ubuntu Unity](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/01/install-important-lenses-in-ubuntu.html)): `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jsevi83/unity; sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/lenses; sudo apt-get update` (of course with _linebreaks instead of semi-colons_)? If so, did you get any errors?

Comment: @HarrisRubin - if you are happy with the answer below - please accept it by clicking the tick button next to the answer.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like the PPA `ppa:jsevi83/unity` is not available anymore.

Before you follow the instructions, make sure you know what it means to play around in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file: ([Wiki.Debian: SourcesList](http://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList), [Help.Ubuntu: Repositories/CommandLine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine), [Help.Ubuntu: Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)).
You'll have to install the Lenses you are looking for from different sources:

1. For the Contact Lens

   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/lenses`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install scope-contacts-google`
   - `sudo apt-get install lens-contacts`
2. The PPA for Tomboy Lens ([Webupd8: Unity Tomboy Lens](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/search-through-your-tomboy-notes-with-unity-tomboy-lens/)) is not available for 12.04.
   Add the follwing lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (open with su privileges).

   - `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy/ubuntu oneiric main`
   - `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy/ubuntu oneiric main`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install unity-lens-tomboy`
     This may not work as you expect as it installs a version of the Lens that is not tested for 12.04, but it was the only version I was able to find.
3. YouTube Lens ([OMG!Ubuntu!: Unity YouTube Lens Updates with Browser Free Video Playback](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/unity-youtube-lens-updates-with-browser-free-video-playback/))

   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/lenses`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install lens-video scope-youtube`
4. I could not find a Books Lens for 12.04. You could try to add the ppa manually (*note that you'll add the version for Oneiric 11.10*).
   Add the follwing lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (open with su privileges).

   - `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/davidc3/books-lens/ubuntu oneiric main`
   - `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/davidc3/books-lens/ubuntu oneiric main`
   - And then:
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install unity-lens-books`

This might or might not work.

1. Grooveshark Lens ([OMG!Ubuntu!: Search Grooveshark Tracks From the Unity Music Lens](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/search-grooveshark-tracks-from-the-unity-music-lens/))

   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install unity-scope-grooveshark`