# Search document by keyword using Unity Lenses

Tags: lenses, search

Say, I have many documents in my computer and I just want to find one document which contains some specific word(s) in it. I can't even remember the type or name of the document.

I tried to achieve this with Unity (Documents & folders) lenses, but it seems Ubuntu only looking for the names (of files and folders) but not looking inside of the documents.

Please advise whether I can achieve my goal using Ubuntu or not.

Comment: I don't know about a Unity lens, but it would be fairly easy to write a script to do this, but it would potentially take a long time to run--as it would be opening every file and scanning word by word.  Useful for finding one file you lost but not very practical for daily use.

Comment: very much time and resource consuming. It needs to index all files on Hard Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to install and use [Recoll Lens](https://askubuntu.com/a/116147/46531):

> Recoll is a full text search desktop tool which indexes the contents
>   of many file formats including OpenOffice, MS Office, PostScript, MP3
>   and other audio files, JPEG and more. Besides regular searches, Recoll
>   also lets you perform some advanced operations like searching for the
>   author, file size, file format as well as operators like "AND" or
>   "OR".
>
> Unity Recoll Lens lets you use Recoll from Dash, without having to
>   open any additional GUI. The lens comes with a few filters like Text,
>   Spreadsheet, Presentation, Media or Message, but for more advanced
>   searches, you'll have to manually enter the Recoll search query.
>   Examples: author:"john doe" metallica OR megadeth /2007 (all documents
>   from 2007 or older) dir:/path/to/dir (filters content from
>   /path/to/dir directory).

Comment: Why this is not made available in Ubuntu software centre?

Comment: do you know of an alternative to Recoll? The developer said that it won't continue support for the lens/scopes, the recoll app is still under development, just not the lens/scope

Answer (score 0):

If the text is stored as [plain text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) inside the document file (whether or not the file itself is composed entirely of plain text), then you can search for it from the command-line with a recursive [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/grep.1.html). This doesn't require indexing first, but searching through all your files takes a very long time so if you ever have to do this more than a couple of times for your whole disk, you should use an indexing search utility instead (like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/145417/22949)).

1. Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Change directory to the top of whatever you want to search. For example, to search everything in your home directory, do `cd ~`. To search everything on your machine, do `cd /`. To search everything in an external drive called DocDrive do `cd /media/DocDrive`. If a directory has spaces in its name, enclose it in quotes (e.g., `cd '/media/Documents Drive'`.
3. Run a recursive `grep` as follows:

   ```
   grep -Rs 'word or phrase you are looking for' .
   ```

Alternatively, you can skip step 2 and, instead of `cd`ing to the folder you want to look inside, replace the `.` in step 3 with the name of the folder you want to look inside.

If you want to search through all files including those you don't ordinarily have access to, you can run `grep` as [`root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user) with [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html):

```
sudo grep -Rs 'word or phrase you are looking for' .
```