# Is there a System Monitor Lens?

Tags: hard-drive, lenses, system-info

I really want to know if there is a System Monitor lens out there. If this doesn't exist, it would be awesome to see system properties in a lens such as HDD usage, RAM, and another properties.

Answer (score 2):

No, for other lenses that are available see [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available), better use conky for that feature. Otherwise System Monitor Indicator are also available, I guess for that matter.

Try [OMG! Ubuntu! - Tag Articles: conky](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/conky/) for good conky's, that are otherwise available.