# Is there a Facebook lens?

Tags: lenses, facebook

Is there a Facebook lens in Ubuntu 12.10? Few of my friends are addicted to facebook and would love to use Ubuntu if it comes with facebook lens. Does anyone know how to install facebook lens (if it exists)?

Comment: Gwibber lens include facebook

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any specialized Facebook lenses for Ubuntu yet (11-October-2012)

- [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)

Comment: @tachyons Gwibber lens seems to be for Ubuntu 11.04 and 12.10. I need lens for Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ this question is perfectly On-topic, AFAIK. The discussion was [here on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate). I think it is an upcoming feature questions, which considered on-topic there.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't see that post.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ No need to sorry. There was a discussion about this topic. I think, we're going to update the [Faq] too