# How to search Google in Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, search, google

How do you get Dash to search Google results?

Comment: I vote for reopening, because this question has good, valid answers and the duplicate is a closed question with no answers.

Comment: I cast the last vote to reopen this.  But I'm removing the 11.10 tag, so its a more general-focus question, rather than version-specific

Comment: @qbi This is a old question. What's the point of re-opening it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find one for Google, but there is a Unity lens available for DuckDuckGo (which also is a search engine, with the advantage that it doesn't track you).

To install it type the following commands into your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:w-vollprecht/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install duckduckgo-len
```

For other good lenses you can also have a look here: [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)

Answer (score 0):

There are different lenses for Unity to search Google. Here in the link below you'll find a wide range of Google search related lenses. Hope this will be enough for you.

[What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)