# What are the different Unity Web-apps that are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, webapps

Now that Ubuntu is officially supporting Web-apps I just wanted to know what are the different Web-apps that are available out there.

I know the most basic ones just add an icon in the Launcher when the site is opened.

I am more interested in useful ones like the gmail-webapp, which manipulates the Messaging Indicator menu.

I hope this question serves as a one-stop point similar to the likes of
[What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)
[What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Comment: `apt-cache search unity-webapps | grep "Unity Webapp for"` May helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the different unity-webapps that can be installed in 12.10

By default 12.10 comes with all the webapps. In case if you want to install manually, then use the command

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-*
```

Note: Currently these apps will work on Firefox/Chromium browser

- Amazon Cloud Reader

  Package name: unity-webapps-amazoncloudreader
- [Angry Birds](http://www.angrybirds.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-angrybirds
- [BBC News](http://www.bbc.com/news/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-bbcnews
- [Cut The Rope](https://docs.google.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-cuttherope
- [Facebook](http://facebook.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-facebookapps
- [Facebook Messenger](https://www.facebook.com/mobile/messenger)

  Package name: unity-webapps-facebookmessenger
- [GMail](http://gmail.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-gmail
- Google Reader

  Package name: unity-webapps-googlecalendar
- [Google docs](https://docs.google.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-googledocs
- [Google +](http://google.com/+)

  Package name: unity-webapps-googleplus
- [Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-grooveshark
- [Hulu Player](http://www.hulu.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-hulu-player
- [last.fm](http://last.fm)

  Package name: unity-webapps-lastfm-radio
- [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-launchpad
- [Libre FM](http://libre.fm/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-librefm
- [Linkedin](http://linkedin.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-linkedin
- [Live Mail](http://mail.live.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-livemail
- [Mail ru](http://mail.ru)

  Package name: unity-webapps-mail-ru
- [News blur](http://www.newsblur.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-newsblur
- [Pandora](http://www.pandora.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-pandora-com
- [QQ Mail](http://mail.qq.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-qq-mail
- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-reddit
- [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-tumblr
- [Twitter](http://twitter.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-twitter
- [VKcom](http://vkcom.net/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-vkcom
- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-wordpress-com
- [Yahoo Mail](http://mail.yahoo.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-yahoomail
- [Yahoo News](http://news.yahoo.com/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-yahoonews
- [Yandex Music](http://music.yandex.ru/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-yandex-music
- [Yandex News](http://news.yandex.ru/)

  Package name: unity-webapps-yandexnews
- [YouTube](http://youtube.com)

  Package name: unity-webapps-youtube