# How to change geolocation for Unity News Lens results?

Tags: 12.10, configuration, lenses

I've installed the Unity News Lens as per the instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available/143983#143983).

The lens uses geolocation to provide results from local news sources. This is a great lens - except **it geolocated me incorrectly**.  I'm currently in Wakefield, Rhode Island, USA, and it displays results appropriate for Wakefield, West Yorkshire, UK.

***Is there a way to reconfigure the news lens's geolocation?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently none, but a fix for your issue should be available in an update in a few hours.

(Due to a mistake, the newsfeed only used the geolocated city name, without the country name. This is fixed. Nevertheless, the ability to set manually a location is on the roadmap.)

Comment: Living in a commonly named town is not awesome in this case.  I'm getting Wakefield, MA results now but that's a lot closer!  Any chance you can add a state/county/province (whatever the country subdivision might be called) field?  Looking forward to the configuration tool, thank you :)