# How to List all available apps on my machine

Tags: 12.10, unity, unity-dash

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, with the unity dash. I would like to List all available apps on my machine. Start menu style in other words.

Dash is hard for me to use unless I know the name of what I am looking for.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/86476/47291

Answer (score 4):

Open the Software Center and click the "Installed" button in the toolbar to see a list of applications that you currently have installed:

[image]

The Software Center is the icon in the Unity launcher that looks like this:

[image]