# What do the listed unity lenses do?

Tags: unity, lenses, search

Ubuntu 12.04 synaptic package manager shows these unity lenses:

- unity-lens-applications
- unity-lens-files
- unity-lens-music
- unity-lens-video

What do the lenses do? And do they send dash searches or any other searches to ubuntu servers or other servers?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Unity Applications Lens](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-applications): a daemon that exposes you applications with their usage statistics and status to Unity.
2. [Unity Files Lens](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-files): a daemon exposing your files and file history to Unity.
3. [Unity Music Lens](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-music): slams your music face first into the dash so you can get your grubby little paws around your collection faster than you can say bon-jovi's-greatest-lovesongs-volume-four.
4. [Unity Videos Lens](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-video): a lens for Unity to search local and remote videos.

For more available lens for Unity, check: [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)

Comment: What interest me most is, which of the lenses sends info to ubuntu servers? It looks like the unityvideolens does it. Do you know? I think these lenses are spy tools. I have already removed the shopping, music and video scopes. If I remove all the lenses listed in my question, will unity then still work? Thanks.

Comment: It will work... Anyway, you can install them back when you want.

Comment: You have not answered the original question. The interest here is: Which of these lenses stay on the computer, and which make contact (and send data to) other servers.