# Will lenses or scopes that worked in 12.04 work in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, lenses, scopes

Am I able to install a lens or a scope in 13.04 that I had used before in 12.04?
Are the lenses and scopes build earlier ([What lenses are available for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)) able "to just work" on 13.04?

Looking forward to Recoll Lens & News Lens again if this is the case that what has worked will work just the same on 13.04.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [Ubuntu Meeting Log](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek1201/UbuntuTechOverview):

> 67 [17:27]  pawel_st asked: â€‹â€†is lens/scopes api
>   stable/going to be stabilized with 12.04; will backwards compatibility
>   be maintained from now, or is it still a moving target?
>
> 68 [17:28]  the lens API had to be changed between Oneiric
>   (11.10) and Precise (12.04), because the original way of doing thing
>   wasn't going to be efficient enough
>
> 69 [17:28]  but the new API should be all but set in stone
>   70 [17:28]  the changes to the API, by the way, were not
>   very drastic

The API should be pretty much set in stone now, so lenses that worked with 12.04 (after the 11.10 API rewrite) should be still compatible with 13.04.

Comment: That information is a bit out of date.  There will be changes to the scope API between 13.04 and 13.10, for instance.  I haven't looked at what the changes were between 12.04 and 13.04 though.

Comment: I tried to install lenses but they did not work.