# Is it possible to add things such as internet searches to the default unity search?

Tags: search

If I wanted to search the internet from the Unity search utility, is it possible to add that? Would it be possible to add something to it that shows only internet shopping results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use `website lenses` and not all websites have them. I will give you an example with this site:

Install the Ask Ubuntu lens:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-askubuntu
```

In your Dash, you will get an askubuntu icon. See screenshot below after I have searched for 'ubuntu'.

[image]

Here is a list of available unity lenses: [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)