# Adding lenses and scopes to Unity in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, lenses, scopes

Ok, so I've recently gone through [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available), and want to add some of the scopes mentioned there. I wanted to add the scope for Wikipedia, so I used the following code :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-wikipedia
```

I can add the ppa and run the update just fine. 
But when I install the lens, the terminal pops out this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-lens-wikipedia
```

What is it exactly that I'm missing out here? Any ideas?

Comment: Tried it. No luck. Now its saying `E: Unable to locate package unity-lens-utilities`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

visit [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=unity-lens-wikipedia)

Package `unity-lens-wikipedia` is not released for trusty (14.04) yet.

Also visit [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/scopes_packagers?dist=trusty) and Head packages for update.

Comment: Oh, alright then. I'll mark this. Would be great if they release it for trusty. Thanks for the help!