# what do you mean by DASH? I have not come across this on other operating syatems

Tags: unity-dash

what do you mean by  DASH? I have not come across this on other operating systems. Some one asked me to help them so I don't know your jargon

Answer (score 0):

The Dash is Ubuntu's equivalent of the start menu. From it you can do a lot of useful tasks. Here is an overview.

Press Super to open it. You may know super as the "Windows Key" - it opens the start menu in Windows.

When you open the dash you'll see an overview of recent programs and file / folder.

[image]

You can search just by typing, that will show Applications, Reference and shopping suggestions. You can use the keyboard to navigate to the desired item:

[image]

Then there are other Scopes or lenses, have a look at [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available) for a list of them.

These scopes include Applications, Documents, Videos, Music, Photos and Social Media messages:

[image][image][image][image]

This is a versatile way of using the keyboard to reach any file or application - I used it a lot when I had unity.