# DuckDuckGo lens for Unity 16.04

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

Does anyone know of a DuckDuckGo lens for Ubuntu unity 16.04? A google lens would also be okay. I've had a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available) and there is no installation package.

Comment: No. That is the same one on the link that I posted. It only works on trusty

Comment: You might want to ask https://launchpad.net/~w-vollprecht

Comment: The whole program would have to be redesigned. It uses a dependency which doesn't work on 16.04. Plus, it was last modified in 2012